# Demoting SBS 2008 to be a member server

Tags: domain-controller, windows-sbs-2008

I have migrated a domain from SBS 2008 to Server 2012 R2, transferring FSMO roles, DHCP, DNS etc. The 2012 server is now a domain controller.

Exchange has already been decommissioned with mail migrated to Office 365.

Is it possible to demote the SBS 2008 server, but keep it on the domain as a file server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft license for SBS does not allow that. You need to reinstall the machine with a regular Windows Server license.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How long will the SBS server remain active if I don't demote it?

Comment: 21 days.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469604%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: It appears to be 30 days grace for SBS 2008 after migrating FSMO roles to another server.